# In jbehave is it possible to use parameterised tabular parameter?

Tags: groovy, jbehave

Let's say i have main  app code that changes file names using some pattern. In jbehave story i want to move this pattern and expected file name to "Examples". Problem is "expected file name" column should contain patter (previous column). Is it possible to use "variables" in "Examples" section?

story file

```
Given that exist file named originalFName
When …
Than file name should be expectedFName

Examples:
|pattern    | originalFName | expectedFName   |
|someString | pattern.txt   | AAA_pattern.rtf |
```

grrovy

```
@Given('that exist file named $originalFName')
void isFileExist(@Named('originalFName') String fName) {…}

@Than('file name should be expectedFName')
void fNameShouldBe(@Named('expectedFName') String expectedFName) {…}
```

So i wonder is possible to get, when compiled (in this case)

originalFName == someString.txt

expectedFName == AAA_someString.rtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many ways to implement this. for example

```
Given fileNamePart
When exist file named originalFName
When …
Than file name should be expectedFName

Examples:
|fileNamePart| originalFName | expectedFName   |
|someString  | %s.txt        | AAA_%s.rtf      |
```

and in code just replace `%s` with `fileNamePart`:

```
originalFName = String.format(originalFName,fileNamePart)
```

instead of `%s` + `String.format` you could use regexp, or dynamic groovy evaluation...

Comment: thank you. I was hoping it is possible to do this using just jbehave, without String.format/replace. But this will also do the trick